# java android - fit items on a image background with different screen size

Tags: java, android, eclipse, button, background

This is my first post and i have (i think) a uncommon request...

I'm programming on the last Eclipse Mac, for every android SDK, and i'm using more XML for layout than runtime... So i search a solution in XML if possible.

Here is the situation: i work with an image background wich simulate item like buttons, image, text... etc. On this image, i put buttons, image, and text (buttonview textview etc...) and place it precisely on their places on the image. This solution is very powerful to have good design BUT, if i change the resolution of the screen, and/or its size, each item won't be at its place, and will be translated (horiz and/or vertic) for some "dp"... (and yes i use dp, not mm or px or whatever)

I'm really embarrased because i think thanks to "dp" it keep proportionnality but.. not !

My question is how can i fix my items at their places on the image background, for different screen size/resolution !!

Thanks in advance everyone,
My Best From Lyon,France

Answer (score 1):

First realise that if you want to make it pixel perfect for all screen sizes your out of luck.

Second accept that you can't make it perfect for all screen sizes.

Third you can get far with creating different layout for different screen sizes. You can read a lot about supporting multiple screen sizes [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). One important thing to take from here is that you can make layout for the different screen sizes or different density sizes.

Comment: Thanks fo your reply Warpzit but... do you now how many screen (size/resolution possibilities) are there for android devices ?? it's just NOT thinkable, and i'm pretty sure there is a solution, many applications use background image and put item on it.

And yes i realize it can't be perfect as iOS design, but when i see some Android app (and many) i think android has really big capacities about design, no ?

Comment: Yes but you gotta realise how they make their designs. Besides using dp they put up views with linearlayout as parents and with weight parameters. and similar. This is how you would achieve it. Im sorry there is no easy way out.

Comment: Oh and another thing. Dont use a background which want buttons on fixed positions. Use a simple background that work for any screen and let your views/buttons/etc. have custom graphic.

Comment: Aha Sometimes you know when you work for different firms, you don't have choice : when they said "use this background" ... you use this background ! ;)

Comment: Yes but then what you do is simply to cut out the graphic which is used for buttons views etc. and make the background look uniform somehow. There is NO other way to make it work properly.